# How to Register and UnRegister events for Interrupt

Tags: c, events, event-handling, interrupt, interrupt-handling

Its not on Standard C, I was trying to develop application in C. Here is the scenario:Its like a power mode implementation of a processor, so that when the processor, wakes from sleep, an interrupt will be generated, so that if i have an event callback at that point i could wake my other module to do its process.For this, I m trying to implement linkedlist using static allocation for accessing memory pool, so that when a callback is registered, it is stored in the memory pool. So when a callback is triggered, it sends a event notification to the modules which is registered.

But i m not sure how to implement it. Kindly provide a way to implementation

Comment: Hello Sur, you'll need to give more details. Standard C doesn't have a concept of interrupts (or event handling). You'll need to tell us what operating system, what type of interrupt you're talking about, and what "event handling" mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean signals? Like when you get a crash or a divide by zero? Here is a posix example of trapping signals:

```
void abortHandler( int signum, siginfo_t* si, void* unused )
{
   const char* name = NULL;
   switch( signum )
   {
      case SIGABRT: name = "SIGABRT";  break;
      case SIGSEGV: name = "SIGSEGV";  break;
      case SIGBUS:  name = "SIGBUS";   break;
      case SIGILL:  name = "SIGILL";   break;
      case SIGFPE:  name = "SIGFPE";   break;
      case SIGPIPE: name = "SIGPIPE";  break;
   }

   if ( name )
      printf( "Caught signal %d (%s)\n", signum, name );
   else 
      printf( "Caught signal %d\n", signum );
}

void trapSignals()
{
   struct sigaction sa;
   sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
   sa.sa_sigaction = abortHandler;
   sigemptyset( &sa.sa_mask );

   sigaction( SIGABRT, &sa, NULL );
   sigaction( SIGSEGV, &sa, NULL );
   sigaction( SIGBUS,  &sa, NULL );
   sigaction( SIGILL,  &sa, NULL );
   sigaction( SIGFPE,  &sa, NULL );
   sigaction( SIGPIPE, &sa, NULL );
}
```